# ImportError no notebook jupyter apesar de instalar a biblioteca chamada

Tags: pip, ipython-notebook

Eu tentei importar uma biblioteca, mas não parece ser adicionado ao notebook jupyter

```
import sys

print("sys.executable:\n",sys.executable)
print("sys.path:\n",sys.path)

from textblob import TextBlob
```

E isso me dá

> ```
>     sys.executable:
>      /usr/bin/python3
>     sys.path:
>      ['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
> '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
> '/home/mike/.ipython']
>
>     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-2-ab115a97c7b9> in <module>()
>          10 print("sys.path:\n",sys.path)
>          11 
>     ---> 12 from textblob import TextBlob
>          13 import nltk
>          14 from scipy import spatial
>
>     ImportError: No module named 'textblob'
> ```

E funciona bem com o intérprete

```
(mybot_env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/mybot$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import textblob
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)
>>>
```

Para resolver o problema, tentei

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
python -m  ipykernel install
```

Mas não funciona.

Comment: Você tentou instalar o `textblob`? Usando a [doc](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html): `pip install -U textblob` e
`python -m textblob.download_corpora`

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Sim, e funciona bem com o intérprete

Comment: Em qual versão do Python instalou? 2 ou 3?

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim 3.5.2